# JQuery Form Submit() not working for SocketIO client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, socket.io

I have a form for a chat client that is supposed to submit a message to a Socket IO server and display it in the chat. My view can receive messages from other remote clients and displays them on my page in the list so I know the Socket IO server is working, I think I'm just too terrible with jQuery and front-end to get the submit form working and I'm stumped.

I have a form with an id of "target" that should trigger the submit() when the send button is pressed, but nothing happens. How can I get the text from the form input to append to the unordered list with id "messages"?

From my HTML:

```html
       <div class="panel-body">
          <ul id="messages" class="media-list">
          </ul>
       </div>

       <form action="" id="target">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="m" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" autocomplete="off"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Send</button>
            </span>
        </div>
       </form>
```

My internal JS:

```js
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var socket = io();
            $("#target").submit(function(){
                console.log($('#m').val());
                socket.emit('response message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
         console.log("From user " + msg);
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
            socket.on('response message', function(msg){
         console.log("From agent " + msg);
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
            });
        });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your button type, you need to specify submit for it to be a submit action on the form.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Send</button>
```